# What initiated the Starhip/SuperHeavy detonation?

Tags: range-safety, spacex-super-heavy

Manual control from a human in a bunker pushing a Big Red Button, or did the autonomous flight safety system self-detonate?

Answer (score 10):

The flight termination system on Starship/Super Heavy is fully autonomous, and FAA notes confirm that it activated.

However, the first explosion appears to initiate from the base of Super Heavy.  The Super Heavy flight termination system is installed in the common bulkhead between the fuel and oxidizer tanks, and would cause an explosion starting in the middle of the booster.  This first explosion was probably caused by structural failure of the oxidizer tank, with the second explosion being caused by FTS activation.

Comment: what FAA notes are you referring to?

Comment: @ErinAnne he's right about the AFTS & FAA, at least according to a reporter for the Washington Post [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/wapodavenport/status/1649109929968402444?cxt=HHwWmICwtc6v6OItAAAA). I don't see any "FAA notes" on the event though.